# Add button not show after show data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

After ajax success, data show in rows but if I want to add a new row at that time add button not shows.[image]

[image]

My code:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h3>Add Video Detail</h3>
       <form id="insertvideo" method="post">
       <table id="addrow" width="100%">
        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add"/></td>
          <tr class="clonetr">
                <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video description<input type="text"  id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video Links<input type="text"  id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       </form>  
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 13px; margin-left: 400px;">
       <button type="submit" id="btn-update"   value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-3 offset-1">Save</button>
   </div>

  <script>
      $(function(){
        $(".addButton").click(function(){
            $('.clonetr:last').clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
        });

        $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
            if($('.deleteButton').length > 1)

               $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            else
                alert('Atleast one required.');

        });
    });
   var mainCatId = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/WebsiteContentController/fetchSubDetail",
                type: "POST",
                data: {mainCatId:mainCatId},
                dataType:'html',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#addrow').html(response);
                    console.log(response);
                }
             });

   </script>
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
I want to add a new row but add button show to add a new row.

Comment: Your html is wrong, you should not have a `<td>` directly in the `<table>` it should be either `<table><tbody><tr><td>` or `<table><tr><td>`

Comment: Also in you response, you use `$('#addrow').html(response);` that means you replace the entire content of the table. that's why your add button is removed.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen How can I show `add` button

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't run your ajax, this will only be a guess on how to fix it.

First, fix the table by adding the missing `<tr>`:

```
<table id="addrow" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clonetr">
    <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td>Video description<input type="text" id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td>Video Links<input type="text" id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now to clear the table but leave the add button:

```
$('#addrow tr:not(:first)').remove();
$('#addrow').append(response);
```

So now it looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/WebsiteContentController/fetchSubDetail",
    type: "POST",
    data: {mainCatId:mainCatId},
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('#addrow tr:not(:first)').remove();
        $('#addrow').append(response);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

To clear the newly created row, try with:

```
$(".addButton").click(function(){
    $('.clonetr:last').clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
    $("#addrow tr:last input").val("");
});
```

Comment: Lovbo Andersen It adds row but not blank it shows last row data in it.

Comment: @farhantechno What does your response looks like?

Comment: Lovbo Andersen I upload a new image

Comment: After click `add` button my third-row show previous data in it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// addd for Vendor Origin in admin zone
 $(".addorigin").on("click", function (e){
    $('.origintable tr:last').before('<tr class="origindiv">                            <td >   <input type="text"  /><i class="fa fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Sender Number."></i></td><td ><input type="text"  /><i class="fa fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter sender name."></i></td> <td><div class="rorigin"><a href="JavaScript:Void(0);" class="removeorigin btn btn-primary-outline btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div></td>                     </tr>');
    });

 //remove row
 $('.origintable').on('click','.removeorigin',function() {
     $(this).closest("tr.origindiv").remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="text-center origintable">
                        <tr class="origindiv">
                            <td >
                            <input type="text" /><i class="fa fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Sender Number."></i>
                            </td>
              <td >
                            <input type="text"  /><i class="fa fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter sender name."></i>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addorigin btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More Row</a>
```

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the OP's problem, Please take your time and read the question carefully. The OP states that after he loads data with ajax then the add button is removed.

Comment: Also Ajit, its bad practice to post examples that contains invalid html, you cant be having multiple elements with the same id `templatename`

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success function, you added a code like this.

```
 $('#addrow').html(response);
```

`html()` function will replace everything inside your `addrow` element. so the add button will be replaced with your response data. please use add button in separate section or add a new container to append the response data.